# How to disable the voice that says the text I hover over in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, voiceover

I am a newbie in the Mac world, I have a Mac mini, and suddenly yesterday I found it crazy, as when I hover overy any text with my mouse it says it.

A friend of mine told me about this problem and how to solve but I forgot, because in that time I didn't have a Mac and didn't care.

How do I disable this effect?

**UPDATE:**
I got from the below answers that this effect called **VoiceOver**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The feature is called 'VoiceOver'.

To disable it use the Universal Preference Pane or press "Command-F5"

Preference Pane:

1. Go to the Apple Menu and choose System Preferences...
2. You then want to click on Universal Access (bottom right) and choose the radio button that says Off under VoiceOver. You'll also notice there is a keyboard command to turn this on (9/10 why it gets turned on): Command - F5 which can be used to turn it off as well.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably (accidentally) enabled VoiceOver. Deactivate it like this:

- Click on the Apple icon in the top left corner
- Click **System Preferences**
- Click **Universal Access**
- Disable VoiceOver